# Display the columns of a SQL Server table in ASP.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, html-table

I have been looking for the solution of this problem through every single page that google can provide to me, but I couldn't find the exact one that can solve it.

I think the solution would be simple, but I'm not expert of C# & ASP.NET MVC, but been working on web development for a while.

Situation: I have a database.

- Table name: `MyData`.
- Column names: ID, Name, Field and Definitions, and I have some values under each column.

I used ADO.Net Entity Data Model to connect my exist database, and those models are under `.edmx` / `.tt` folder.

```
public partial class MyData
{
    public MyData(){ }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
}
```

Then I add a MVC5 controllers with views, using EF that points to the model I just generated from database.

```
namespace Mytest1.Controllers
{
    public class MyDataController : Controller
    {
        private MyDatadb db = new MyDataEntities();

        // GET: MyData
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.MyData.ToList());
        }
        ...
```

And I right-clicked to create the view of Index, Edit, Create.... Below is Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mytest1.MyData>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyData";
}

<h2>MyData</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>  
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Definition)
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {...
```

Now I can display the values under each column and the webpage gives me the table by processing the Index view.

So the question is that, I don't want to show those values. I want webpage to show the upper level information of this database. So I'd like to have a table which first row is `MyData` and the rest row below are ID, Name, Field and Definition. That simple. But I don't know how to do it.

What I'm thinking about is to add this in the current model

```
    public class showColumn : MyData{
    // 1. retrieve how many columns are in MyData
    // 2. Return the values of those columns that have counted in step 1 
}
```

And then I create a new table in Index.cshtml say:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.showColumn)
        </th>

    </tr>
```

Would this thinking be a possible way to achieve this solution? Or if anyone can give me a better way to solve it, I'll appreciate it so much!

Comment: Could you please moc up what you want in paint and add it to the question. I'm finding it hard to figure out what your trying to do. Please comment when you're done so I get a notification.

Also (I would do it for you but I'm 90 rep of edit!!!) I would recomend adding the asp.net-mvc tag to this question as most peeps look for that when answering questions.

Comment: So basically those code blocks above are petty much describing my problem. if you think the pseudocode I wrote(

public class showColumn : MyData{
    // 1. retrieve how many columns are in MyData
    // 2. Return the values of those columns that have counted in step 1 
})
 is a possible way to solve this problem, then my question would be how to make the pseudo to the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sys.tables and sys.columns .
just write a select statement on those tables

```
select * from sys.tables
select * from sys.columns
```

Comment: Yes that'd be a possible way, but I'd like to use C# to make it happen. I'm thinking to use foreach loop to actually count how many columns in this table then return the value of these columns that have been counted.

Comment: I plan to inject raw sql query to make this happen. Do I need to put this query in Model or Controller?

Comment: try to do actions in controllers . and just keep classes in models